# Inherit from a class with factory method

Tags: c#, inheritance, async-await, factory-pattern

I have a class with some properties that need to be initialized as soon as I create an instance. However, the initialization of these properties involves IO operations and so I decided to apply the Factory Pattern as suggested here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Here an example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Property1 { get; private set; }
    public int Property2 { get; private set; }
    public int Property3 { get; private set; }

    private MyObject()
    {
        // do something
    }

    private static async Task<MyObject> CreateIstanceAsync()
    {
        MyObject myObject = new();
        myObject.Property1 = await CalculateProperty1();
        myObject.Property2 = await CalculateProperty2();
        myObject.Property3 = await CalculateProperty3();
        return myObject;
    }

    private static async Task<int> CalculateProperty1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 10;
    }

    private static async Task<int> CalculateProperty2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 20;
    }

    private static async Task<int> CalculateProperty3()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 30;
    }
}
```

Now I need to implement another class derived from MyObject like this:

```
public class MyObject2 : MyObject
{
    public int Property4 { get; private set; }

    private static async Task<int> CalculateProperty4()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 30;
    }
}
```

But there are at least two problems:

1. MyObject2 cannot inherit from MyObject because the constructor is
   private.
2. I don't know how to write the MyObject2.CreateIstance
   method.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Why is `MyObject`'s constructor `private`? What's preventing you from making it `protected` and allowing you to inherit from it?

Comment: @madreflection yes, it is private. I fixed the text in the question. However I decided to make it private because I don't want derived classes to have a constructor. I want all derivatives to use a CreateIstance method.

Comment: There's no way to enforce that. Not at the instantiation phase, anyway.

Comment: Is there any other pattern to achieve the same result?

Comment: Inheritance is a problem here, because the Open-Closed Principle is "open for extension, but closed for modification", but your base class is "open for extension as long as you do it my way", which is not exactly "open".

Comment: it sounds like your class is doing too much: holding the data as well as retrieving the data. i'd do a separation of concerns analysis

Comment: For the sake of completeness, MyObject is a ViewModel (see MVVM pattern) in a WPF application.

Comment: For ViewModels, you would never want to use async factories. Instead, [data bind to values that update when the data arrives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).